# Getting error in my mysql code: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to solve error but i dont have any idea how to solve please help me.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'create table jobseeker(j_id  first_name varchar(20),last_name varchar(20),phone_' at line 5

```
create table admin(primary key,admin_name varchar(20),admin_password varchar(20));

create table jobseeker(j_id int primary key,first_name varchar(20),last_name varchar(20),phone_no int(11),email_id varchar(20),address1 varchar(30), address2 varchar(30),qualification varchar(20),birthday_date date,gender varchar(10),field varchar(50),year of passing int(11), board varchar(20),zip int(11),city varchar(20),state varchar(20),username varchar(20),password varchar(20));

create table job seeker job(id int primary key,j_id int(10),c_name varchar(20),post varchar(20),foreign key references(j_id int foregin key references job seeker(id)));

create table company news(n_id int primary key,c_id int(11)primary key,information varchar(50),link varchar(50));

create table company(c_id int primary key,c_name varchar(20),phone_no int(11),address varchar(20),email_id varchar(20),password varchar(20));
```

Comment: Run SQL statements one at a time. Most interfaces do not support multi-query.

Comment: Learn the sql dialect, debug your own code. This is not a free code-writing and code-correcting website. And **NEVER** store plain-text passwords in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have some errors, but as Bill Karwin said, run SQL statemets one at a time.

In your first statement you dont have a name and a type for your primary key.

```
create table admin(id int primary key,admin_name varchar(20),admin_password varchar(20));
```

In your second statement you have a column named 'year of passing'. It's not allowed, you should use underscore.

```
create table jobseeker(j_id int primary key,first_name varchar(20),last_name varchar(20),phone_no int(11),email_id varchar(20),address1 varchar(30), address2 varchar(30),qualification varchar(20),birthday_date date,gender varchar(10),field varchar(50),year_of_passing int(11), board varchar(20),zip int(11),city varchar(20),state varchar(20),username varchar(20),password varchar(20));
```

Again, check every statement and I recommend you to use some editor with syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Because j_id did not have the data type. Which is int.

Also, the year of passing int(11) can not have spaces. Well, it can f that is what you really want to do. I will recomend you do not. Rather use underscore "_"

Write it like below if you need your spaces for your column name: year of passing` int(11)

```
create table jobseeker(
    j_id int primary key,
    first_name varchar(20),
    last_name varchar(20),
    phone_no int(11),
    email_id varchar(20),
    address1 varchar(30), 
    address2 varchar(30),
    qualification varchar(20),
    birthday_date date,
    gender varchar(10),
    field varchar(50),
    `year of passing` int(11), 
    board varchar(20),
    zip int(11),
    city varchar(20),
    state varchar(20),
    username varchar(20),
    password varchar(20)
);
```

notice that I also have spaces for `year of passing`, this is not recommended. I recommend that you one of the following for that column.

```
year_of_passing int(11)
```

or

```
yearOfPassing int(11)
```